# OLEDBConnection to Excel does not like network share path

Tags: c#, excel, path, oledbconnection

I need to connect to an excel file on a network share o read the workbook. If the file is local, then it works but when the file is on a network share and I use this as my datasoure:

```
"\\Server\\MyShare\\Testing\\InputFiles\\Test_ReportInput.xlsx"
```

it throws this error:

> 'C:\Server\MyShare\Testing\InputFiles\Test_ReportInput.xlsx' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

It pre-pended `C:\` on the original path. Obviously the path nor file exist when C:\ is added.

Does this not work with network shares? Or do I need to tell it somehow not to use C:\?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, just had to do this:

```
"\\\\Server\\MyShare\\Testing\\InputFiles\\Test_ReportInput.xlsx"
```

4 `\` at start.

Answer (score 0):

Can you map your network share so that it has a drive letter and use that?

In Windows Explorer, right-click on the shared folder and select "Map Network Drive...".

*Just saw your 4 slashes solution and that looks better. Thanks.